# Running fselect using Python

Tags: python, svm, libsvm

I am trying to run this python script called fselect in windows 7. It can be downloaded from this website: http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvmtools/ under this name called Feature selection tool. I am running it on Python 2.7.2.Facing a bit of problem running it..

Typed this first in IDLE:

```
>>> import pprint
>>> import sys
>>> print pprint.pprint(sys.path)
>>> sys.path.append("C:\Users\HP\Documents\MATLAB\libsvm-3.11\tools")
>>> import fselect
Usage:  training_file [testing_file]
```

Then the problem is when i type the next part:

Tried this:

```
>>> ./fselect.py TrainVec
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Next tried this:

```
>>> fselect.py TrainVec
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Next tried this:

```
>>> TrainVec

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#7>", line 1, in <module>
    TrainVec
NameError: name 'TrainVec' is not defined
```

Tried this also:

```
>>> TrainVec.mat

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#8>", line 1, in <module>
    TrainVec.mat
NameError: name 'TrainVec' is not defined
```

What is the correct way of typing it? Need some guidance on it...

tried running using cmd but there is an error...

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to run the `fselect.py` directly from the command prompt, make sure that python is set into the path variable. For guidance with that, please read http://people.cis.ksu.edu/~schmidt/200f07/setpath.html.

The script will also invoke `grid.py`. `grid.py` requires `gnuplot` to be there. So ensure that `grid.py` is running properly and if necessary check the paths of the `svm_train`, `svm_test` in the script along with that of `grid.py`.
Hope it will work now.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a tool, you should run it, not import it. And of course you should not try to enter random commands, even if they are valid shell commands, in your Python prompt.

Comment: I cannot, it's so trivial I don't know how to explain this further.

Comment: got to run.. but one more qn: where shld i place the TrainVec file?

Comment: what shld the command be like? It is because when i run it, it returns me this: Usage: C:\Users\HP\Documents\MATLAB\libsvm-3.11\tools\fselect.py training_file [testing_file]

Comment: C:\Users\HP\Documents\MATLAB\libsvm-3.11\tools\fselect.py training_file [testing_file]

Comment: does it matter if it python 3.2 or python 2 series? does it make a difference?

Comment: btw when i run C:\Users\HP\Documents\MATLAB\libsvm-3.11\tools\fselect.py training_file [testing_file], i get SyntaxError: invalid syntax. it pointing to : in the line...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming TrainVec is your data (since you use it in the context of TrainVec.mat it must be a Matlab data file) then run it on the Command Prompt like this:

```
python fselect.py TrainVec.mat
```

The example of `./fselect.py` is intended for Unix systems. Make sure you run the above command in what ever directory you have saved `fselect.py` in.

If you need to write your own scripts to leverage this `.py` file then I refer you [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3980059/how-do-i-use-an-external-py-file) for an example of how to do this.

Comment: what do u mean by command prompt? u mean the idle? or the command line?

Comment: http://windows.microsoft.com/en-GB/windows7/Command-Prompt-frequently-asked-questions

Comment: tried running in command but there seems to be another error.. have updated the question...

Comment: Look here: http://www.swaroopch.com/notes/Python_en:Installation#For_Windows_users and follow the instructions for DOS Prompt

Answer (score 0):

Like the previous answer said, it looks like you are (incorrectly) trying to run the script from inside the Python interpreter. According to the documentation on the page you link to, it  is not a module but a free-standing script and should be run as such:

```
Usage: ./fselect.py training_file [testing_file]
```

Comment: when it run like this, C:\Users\HP\Documents\MATLAB\libsvm-3.11\tools\fselect.py TrainVec.mat [TestVec.mat]
it gives me this error SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: `[]` mean it is an optional argument.